# Размещение кнопки в шапку окна без полей

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, framelesswindowhint, windowflags

Мне нужно разместить кнопку в шапку окна приложения. 
Как это можно сделать? 
Хочу установить на него картинку в виде знака вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.qust = QPushButton(self)
        self.qust.setText("Вопрос")
        self.qust.move(50, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> flags Qt::[**WindowFlags**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)
>
> Этот тип перечисления используется для указания различных свойств оконной системы для виджета. Они довольно необычны, но необходимы в некоторых случаях. Некоторые из этих флагов зависят от того, поддерживает ли их основной оконный менеджер.
>
> **...**

> Qt::**FramelessWindowHint**
>
> Создает окно без полей. Пользователь не может перемещать или изменять размер окна без полей через оконную систему. В X11 результат флага зависит от оконного менеджера и его способности понимать подсказки Motif и/или NETWM. Большинство существующих современных оконных менеджеров могут справиться с этим.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    height = 35

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self.title = QPushButton("Вопрос")
        self.title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;  
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: white;
        """)

        self.closeButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_close)
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #DC143C;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.maxButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_maximize)
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #32CD32;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.hideButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_hide)
        self.hideButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximaze = False

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement))
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False

    def on_click_close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def on_click_maximize(self):
        self.maximaze = not self.maximaze
        if self.maximaze:    self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)
        if not self.maximaze:
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    def on_click_hide(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


class StatusBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.showMessage("Hello StatusBar!")

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Status bar...")
        self.label.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            color: white;
        """)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def showMessage(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #2c2f33;   
        """)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: white;
        """)
        
        self.title_bar = TitleBar(self) 
        self.title_bar.title.clicked.connect(lambda: self.label.setText(
            'Hello World' if not self.label.text() else ''
        ))
        
        self.status_bar = StatusBar(self)

        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.status_bar, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @greymaster что не так?

Comment: нет, все прекрасно, спасибо.